# Setting a parameter to a query inside a stored procedure doesn't work

Tags: mysql

Here is a MySQL request that works without a hitch :

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS my_procedure;

DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test_db;
CREATE DATABASE test_db;
USE test_db;
CREATE TABLE test_table (test_data varchar(255));
INSERT INTO test_db.test_table VALUES ('test_data1');
    
delimiter //

create procedure my_procedure()
begin
    SET @s = 'SELECT * from test_db.test_table';
    PREPARE stmt2 FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt2;
end//

delimiter ;

call my_procedure();
```

Setting the table using a parameter however, doesn't work :

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS my_procedure;

DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test_db;
CREATE DATABASE test_db;
USE test_db;
CREATE TABLE test_table (test_data varchar(255));
INSERT INTO test_db.test_table VALUES ('test_data1');
    
delimiter //

create procedure my_procedure()
begin
    SET @s = 'SELECT * from ?';
    PREPARE stmt2 FROM @s;
    SET @a = 'test_db.test_table';
    EXECUTE stmt2 USING @a;
end//

delimiter ;

call my_procedure();
```

The [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html) says to use "?" for parameters. So what is wrong here ?

Edit : Following answers, using CONCAT does not work :

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS testing;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE testing(IN db VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    # Does work
    SET @query = CONCAT('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ', db, ';');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    SET @query = CONCAT('CREATE DATABASE ', db, ';');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;

    # Doesn't work
    # SET @query = CONCAT('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ', db, ';', 'CREATE DATABASE ', db, ';');
    # PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    # EXECUTE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL testing('test_db');
```

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. Sorry...

Comment: If you have an error please publish in full..

Comment: The error is just the 1064 wrong syntax.

Comment: [SQL syntax for prepared statements does not support multi-statements (that is, multiple statements within a single string separated by ; characters).](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html#:~:text=SQL%20syntax%20for%20prepared%20statements%20does%20not%20support%20multi%2Dstatements%20(that%20is%2C%20multiple%20statements%20within%20a%20single%20string%20separated%20by%20%3B%20characters).)

Comment: You got 2 answers, now you added another totally different question. And obviously you even didn't read the link which I added to my answer. There you can read in  the 2nd line: `The text must represent a single statement, not multiple statements.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Georg Richter, `?` characters can be used as parameter markers to indicate where *data values* are to be bound to the query.

So This is a way to choose the table on which to perform your query :

```
create procedure my_procedure()
begin
    SET @a = 'test_db.test_table';
    SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * from ', @a);
    PREPARE stmt2 FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt2;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for multiple statements. If I put all the statements (DROP, CREATE, etc) in a variable through the use of CONCAT, the error is still there.

Comment: Could you share how have you tested my solution ?

Comment: I edited the question with an example for that :)

Comment: It is not possible. PREPARE / EXECUTE stmt can execute only one query at a time.

Comment: Ah, well that explains it. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Parameter can be used in a prepared statement (both SQL and binary protocol) only for literals.

This is also [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/prepare.html):

*Parameter markers can be used only where data values should appear, not for SQL keywords, identifiers, and so fort*

The benefit of a prepared statement is, that it will be parsed once (during prepare) and executed multiple times afterwards without overhead of parsing, creating execution plan etc. That wouldn't be possible if a parameter marker could be used for a table or column name.

Note: Please don't forget to close your prepared statement with `DEALLOCATE PREPARE` to prevent leaking.